# How to extend an arc to a complete circle?

Tags: python, image, algorithm

Given a binary square array of the fixed size like on the image below.
It is assumed in advance that the array contains an image of a circle or part of it. It's important that this circle is always centred on the image.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dV9Mi.png)

It is necessary to find an effective way to supplement the arc to the full circle, if it's possible.

I've tried to statistically calculate the average distance from the centre to the white points and complete the circle. And it works. I've also tried the Hough Transform to fit the ellipse and determine its size. But both methods are very resource intensive.

1 method sketch:

```
points = np.transpose(np.array(np.nonzero(array))).tolist() # array of one-value points
random.shuffle(points) 
points = np.array(points[:500]).astype('uint8') # take into account only 500 random points

distances = np.zeros(points.shape[0], dtype='int32') # array of distances from the centre of image (40, 40) to some point
for i in xrange(points.shape[0]):
    distances[i] = int(np.sqrt((points[i][0] - 40) ** 2 + (points[i][1] - 40) ** 2))

u, indices = np.unique(distances, return_inverse=True)
mean_dist = u[np.argmax(np.bincount(indices))] # most probable distance
# use this mean_dist in order to draw a complete circle
```

[1 method result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i35sD.png)

2 method sketch:

```
from skimage.transform import hough_ellipse

result = hough_ellipse(array, min_size=..., max_size=...)
result.sort(order='accumulator')
# ... extract the necessary info from result variable if it's not empty
```

Could someone suggest another and effective solution? Thank you!

Comment: Show your attempts!

Comment: This is a valid and good question, but without code it seems very broad and not specific to any of the given tags. It may as well be more suited to other SE sites, such as DSP.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried to statistically calculate the average distance from the centre to the white points and complete the circle.

Well this seems to be a good start. Given an image with `n` pixels, this Algorithm is `O(n)` which is already pretty efficient.

If you want a faster implementation, try using randomization:

Take `m` random sample points from the image and use those to calculate the average radius of the white points. Then complete the circle using this radius.

This algorithm would then have `O(m)` which means that it's faster for all `m < n`. Choosing a good value for `m` might be tricky because you have to compromise between runtime and output quality.

Comment: Yes, it's quite clear. But it doesn't work well enough, because there are millions of such arrays and all of them are different. Therefore this method is not finally appropriate.  There is also a crazy idea to train a neural network to supplement the circle's arc :)

Comment: Do you mean that it's not fast enough or that it doesn't supplement the circle in all cases?

Comment: If it's about speed, show your code. If it's about the outcome, show some cases that don't work.

Comment: At least, It works faster than other approaches. As for non working samples: sometimes it happens that circle shapes are significantly noisy - like [this](http://imgur.com/iODFCCQ)